# Rails as_json include parent object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Hello I'm trying to use as_json to output the parent object as an include.
Here is my code :

```
photo.as_json(:include => [:comments, :likes])
```

This code works, this one doesn't :

```
photo.as_json(:include => [:comments, :likes, :user])
```

I get the error :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `macro' for nil:NilClass
```

Any one ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Seems "p" is Nil - how do you set photo and p ?

Comment: sorry, a typo from my part, it is "photo" for both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using [acts_as_api](https://github.com/fabrik42/acts_as_api) which allows for methods, templates and a lot of cool features that got the work done much easier.

Comment: You may like rabl or jbuilder, YMMV

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
user = User.find(1)    
user.as_json(:include => {:photos => {:include => [:comments, :likes]}})
```

Comment: I wanted the user as a sub object of my photo and not all photos.

Answer (score 0):

you call the "methods" option instead:

```
photo.as_json(:methods => [:user], :include => [:comments, :likes, :user])
```

I've used this in Rails 4.0, ruby 2.0 to bring back what i need.